# Understanding the Difference Between a Distribution and a Process

Tags: probability

I am struggling to understand the difference between a **Multivariate Gaussian Distribution** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and a **Gaussian Process** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process).

Out of these two concepts, I think I understand the **Multivariate Gaussian Distribution** better - a set of $X_1, X_2 ... X_n$ Random Variables can "Jointly" be Distributed by a Gaussian Distribution. Together, this would look something like this:

$$
f(\mathbf{x}|\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n|\boldsymbol{\Sigma}|}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^\mathrm{T}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\right)
$$

Where:

- $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ is the $n$-dimensional vector of mean values (where $\mu_i$ is the mean of the $i$-th random variable $x_i$)
- $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is the covariance matrix with values $\sigma_{11}, \sigma_{12}, \ldots, \sigma_{1n}, \sigma_{21}, \sigma_{22}, \ldots, \sigma_{2n}, \ldots, \sigma_{n1}, \sigma_{n2}, \ldots, \sigma_{nn}$

Now, I think I understand the overall formula of the **Gaussian Process** (https://cs229.stanford.edu/section/cs229-gaussian_processes.pdf):

$$\begin{bmatrix} f(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_m) \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix} m(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ m(x_m) \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k(x_1, x_1) & \cdots & k(x_1, x_m) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ k(x_m, x_1) & \cdots & k(x_m, x_m) \end{bmatrix}\right)$$

Where:

- $f(\cdot) \sim GP(m(\cdot), k(\cdot, \cdot))$.
- $m(x) = E[x]$
- $k(x, x') = E[(x - m(x))(x' - m(x'))]$ for any $x, x' \in X$.

To me, the Multivariate Gaussian Distribution and the Gaussian Process both seem to describe the Joint Probability Distribution for some set of random variables $X_1, X_2 ... X_n$. In both the Multivariate Gaussian Distribution and the Gaussian Process, any subset of of $X_1, X_2 ... X_n$ is also Jointly Normally Distributed.

The only differences between the Multivariate Gaussian Distribution and the Gaussian Process that I see are:

- The presence of the Kernel which can potentially allow for a more flexible choice of variance structure and thus potentially be more useful for describing the behavior of more complex systems. In the same respect, the Gaussian Process has the ability to describe *arbitrary functions* of the set of random variables $X_1, X_2 ... X_n$ whereas the Multivariate Gaussian Distribution does not.
- Also, I do not see any $\sigma_{11}, \sigma_{12}, \ldots, \sigma_{1n}, \sigma_{21}, \sigma_{22}, \ldots, \sigma_{2n}, \ldots, \sigma_{n1}, \sigma_{n2}, \ldots, \sigma_{nn}$ parameters within the Gaussian Process. From an estimation perspective, I think this would imply that $\sigma_{11}, \sigma_{12}, \ldots, \sigma_{1n}, \sigma_{21}, \sigma_{22}, \ldots, \sigma_{2n}, \ldots, \sigma_{n1}, \sigma_{n2}, \ldots, \sigma_{nn}$ do not need to be estimated in the Gaussian Process, but rather the parameters within the choice of Kernel Function $k(x, x')$.

However, I am not sure if I am correct about all this. **Can someone please help me understand the similarities and differences? Are there any real world situations where one of them is more useful than the other and vice versa?**

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you are overthinking it. The Gaussian ***distribution*** describes the distribution of a vector $\mathbf{X}$ that we usually think of being a realization of a random phenomenon at a ***single*** instance of time. A Gaussian ***process*** is a sequence of such vetors $\mathbf{X}_t$ (where $t$ represents time and can be continuous or discrete). To fully describe the Gaussian process we have to specify correlations between $\mathbf{X}_t$ and $\mathbf{X}_s\,.$ Sure: all components of the vectors at all times form a huge matrix that has a Gaussian distribution but so what?

Comment: When you try to generalize multivariate gaussians to infinite dimensions (e.g., probability distributions on a function space), you run into technical problems defining even simple things such as white noise. Gaussian processes are a way to get around these technical problems, by only considering finite numbers of variables at a time, from within the infinite dimensional vector.